using dd with kubuntu to transfer ISO''s tp ubs's
I would like to use dd to make a few different Linux distros on usb using kubuntu. Any direction would be helpful and appreciated.
thanks

This question is similar to: Using 'dd' command to create bootable USB stick. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Now it may be more convenient to use cp to operate than dd.
ex: cp Ubuntu.iso /dev/sdx

If using dd, you only copy one at a time. And it totally erases drive you copy to. Most use a smaller 8GB or so flash drive. If you want multiple ISO on one drive, one common solution is Ventoy. https://www.ventoy.net/en/doc_grub2boot.html If familiar with grub, you can use grub to loopmount boot many ISO as ISO files on one flash drive. I have used grub, but now use SSD as much faster than flash drives.
